# Как добавить товар в корзину?

Tags: php, html

Пытаюсь сделать на PHP добавление товара в корзину. Я присваиваю кнопке атрибут name с id из бд(выглядит это так `name="tovar<тут подставляется id>`") и вывожу ее на страницу(так же там появляется информация о товаре), далее мне нужно по нажатию кнопки добавить товар в корзину. Но я не понимаю как достать значение name конкретно нажатой кнопки. Я новичок поэтому сильно не бейте. Спасибо

```
$showrez = mysqli_query($connection, $sql1);
    while ( ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($showrez)) ){
        echo "<div>".$row2['name']."</div>";
        echo "<div>".$row2['count']."</div>";
        echo "<button name='tovar".$row2['id']."'".">В КОРЗИНУ</button>";
    }
```

Comment: Два варианта: 1. без обновления страницы - это с помощью JS. 2. С обновлением страницы, для этого создаете форму и отправляете на сервер. Вас какой интересует?

Comment: @ЕвгенийНиколаев не хочу показаться наглым, но меня интересуют оба варианта))

Comment: Для обоих этих вариантов серверная часть будет одинаковая. Для хранения данных используйте `coockie`, до тех пор пока не оформят заказ. В JS у вас просто добавится либо `fetch`, либо `ajax` - это для отправки данных на сервер. За место `button` используйте тег `a` получится что-то типо `<a href='cart.php?id="<?=$id?>"'>Добавить</a>`

Comment: @ЕвгенийНиколаев используя тег `a` я тоже могу использовать `class` и `data-value`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если используешь ajax, имеет смысл просто присваивать кнопкам определённый класс и дата-атрибут с Id товара, а потом получать значение этого атрибута

```
<?
    $showrez = $connection->query($sql1);
    while ($row2 = $showrez->fetch_assoc()) {
        // Выводим товары
        ?>
        <div><?= $row2['name'] ?></div>
        <div><?= $row2['count'] ?></div>
        <button class="add-product-btn" data-value="<?= $row2['id'] ?>">В КОРЗИНУ</button>
        <?
    }
?>
<script>
    $(function() {

        // Навешиваем событие click
        $('.add-product-btn').on('click', function() {

            // Получаем Id товара
            let productId = $(this).attr('data-value');

            // ..
            // Производим какие-то действия с имеющимся Id
            // ..
        });
    });
</script>
```

Если обычным способом с перезагрузкой страницы, используй формы

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<button name='tovar".$row2['id']."'"." onClick='korzina(".$row2['id'].")'>В КОРЗИНУ</button>";
```

Далее что тебе удобнее в функции korzina() - можно записать куку, запустить ajax, сделать submit() невидимой формы в невидимом/видимом фрейме, обновит виджет с ценой/количеством товаров на странице.